# Python PIL how cut area inside diagonal line?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I would like to know the area inside the spaces between one line and another and then cut them into separate images.

```
def grid(width, height, wq, hq):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color='white')
    pic = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 
    for i in range(0, width, wq):
        for j in range(0, height, hq):
            pic.line([(i, j), (i + wq, j + hq)], fill="red", width=10)
    img.show()
grid(600,600,300,300)
```

Find the areas, and save the two triangles and the two trapezoids in separate images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/suEgl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to be easy with PIL, though you probably could do it using `ImageDraw.floodfill()` to fill in the trapezoids one at a time and then find their locations using `Numpy`.

I would suggest you use **OpenCV** and its `findContours()`. I would also suggest you ditch full-colour processing if you just want to find an area of one thing and not another thing which reduces processing time and memory pressure. Specifically also, if using **OpenCV** you need to look for white objects on a black background, so I adapted your code to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import cv2

def grid(width, height, wq, hq):
   img = Image.new('L', (width, height), color='white')
   pic = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 
   for i in range(0, width, wq):
      for j in range(0, height, hq):
         pic.line([(i, j), (i + wq, j + hq)], fill="black", width=10)
   return img

im = grid(600,600,300,200)
im.save('result.png')

# Make into Numpy array for OpenCV
na = np.array(im)

# Find the contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(na,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    # Calculate area
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print(f'Contour: {i}, area: {area} pixels')
    # Make new, empty output image
    out = np.zeros((na.shape[0], na.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    # Draw in the contour
    cv2.drawContours(out,[c],0,255,thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.imwrite(f'contour-{i}.png', out)
```

Here are the output images, one per contour, all horizontally merged onto a grey background so you can determine the extent of each:

[image]

Here are the output areas:

```
Contour: 0, area: 27936.5 pixels
Contour: 1, area: 84432.0 pixels
Contour: 2, area: 112819.5 pixels
Contour: 3, area: 28130.0 pixels
Contour: 4, area: 84626.5 pixels
Contour: 5, area: 0.0 pixels
```

There are many more features you can test for such as arc length, centroids, moments, circularity, minimum area but I'll leave that up to you.

You can also use the images generated above as masks and `bitwise_and()` them with your image to extract just the white areas.

Remember that you can do your processing in greyscale but still use the resulting masks and areas and apply them to your original full-colour input image.

---

If you have some objection to using **OpenCV**, note that you could use `scikit-image` and its [label](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) and [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops).

Comment: Thank you very much!
one more question, my class is used to divide and reassemble the images, I wanted to extend it and in addition to the x,y coordinates also work with x,y1 and x1,y (diagonal). What do you think is the best open-licensed library to do this? OpenCV , scikit-image, Pillow? Thx

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. OpenCV is extremely versatile and capable. Maybe ask a fresh question - they are free

Comment: I have opend another question as suggested, this is the title "which Python library is better among OpenCV, Pillow, and scikit-image for cropping and reassembling flat images"